# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset？

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I need get the bitmap from ***IFrameCallback*** which was functioned to deal with the **frame** from a **UVCCamera** preview, but there's comes the exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset

```
private final IFrameCallback callback = new IFrameCallback() {
    @override
    public void onFrame(final ByteBuffer frame) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[frame.remaining()];
            frame.get(bytes);

            if(bytes.length > 0) {
                int offset = frame.arrayOffset();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset);
                ......
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

or if I use **createBitmap** instead of **decodeByteArray**, I got this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer

```
private final IFrameCallback callback = new IFrameCallback() {
    @override
    public void onFrame(final ByteBuffer frame) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_WIDTH, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(frame);
            ......
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Because the preview size is **1280 x 720**, so the problem of **RuntimeException** can be ignored.

Is there any ideas about the first exception to get the **arrayOffset** from **ByteBuffer**?

PS: I know

> UnsupportedOperationException - If this buffer is not backed by an
>   accessible array

My point is: is there any other ways to get the ***arrayOffset***, or if can't do that and how to solve the RuntimeException?

Comment: read teh javadoc: *UnsupportedOperationException - If this buffer is not backed by an accessible Array*.

Comment: Read the javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#arrayOffset--). This is for Java 10. `Throws:
ReadOnlyBufferException - If this buffer is backed by an array but is read-only
UnsupportedOperationException - If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array`

Comment: @Jens Hey, Jens, I know that, and that is why I got the byteBuffer.ayyar() by byteBuffer.get(). The problem is how can I get the arrayOffset and can avoid the exception!

Comment: @frankjorsn frame.get(bytes); Returns a ByteBuffer. You have to assign it to a variable and work on it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since there's no a good solution, I had changed the way to get the **bitmap** from ***IFrameCallback***.

Because I had applied the **UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21** format to the **UVCCamera**:

> uvcCamera.setFrameCallback(frameCallback,
>   UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_NV21);

So, I can get the **bitmap** just transform **YuvImage**:

```
private ChannelBufferOutputStream stream = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(MessageBuffers.dynamicBuffer());
......
private final IFrameCallback callback = new IFrameCallback() {
    @override
    public void onFrame(final ByteBuffer frame) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @override
            public void run() {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[frame.remaining()];
                frame.get(bytes);

                if(bytes.length > 0) {
                    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_WIDTH, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, null);
                    bytes = null;

                    if(yuvImage.getYuvData().length > 0) {
                        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight()), 80, stream);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.buffer().array(), 0, stream.buffer().array().length);
                        ......
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```